# How can I make my dropdown menu remain open when user is hovering over the div but close when they stop?

Tags: javascript

My dropdown menu works, but essentially my menu button is what I'm using as the event for showing the menu, and i set it up so when you hover over the menu, it stays open but if you just hover over the button and then move your mouse without touching the menu with your mouse, it stays open and doesn't close.

```
function showMenu(){
    document.getElementById("dropdown-menu").style.display = "block";
}

function hideMenu(){
    document.getElementById("dropdown-menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `mouseover` event ? You can refer the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event#examples

Comment: Yes the problem I'm unsure how to make it so that the mouseover event can work for both the button which makes the menu show as well as the actual menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach same class to the 2 DOM elements and attach event listener using the class. This a simple sample

```js
document.querySelector('.demo').addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
  document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor="#2be28d";
})
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

.box {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #8a2be2;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <button class="demo">Click me</button>
  <div class="demo box" id="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```